# Breeze JS client with dynamic objects

Tags: breeze

I'm investigating using Breeze for client side caching and querying. Unfortunately the existing web service returns (JSON) objects that for a given type may have variable number and type of fields. They will all have a unique id and a few base fields, but for example a Person may have name, age and address say, and another Person may have name, birthdate and favoriteColor.

What each Person has is described by metadata sent embedded into each object (so each Person also has a metadata field).

Querying is obviously problematic here but assume for now that we will not be querying on any field that is not on all items of a given type.

We are using AngularJS too, in case that is relevant.

My question is, how would one handle this situation using Breeze? Would we be better off just using a simple object cache and "querying" simply by iterating over the cache with a predicate function?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look on Jhon Papa's pluralsight video lecture for querying using client cache on [pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/courses/build-apps-angular-breeze) , which is a complete demonstration of breeze and angularJs. Also you can refer [this](http://getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples)